# Injecting JavaScript in WebkitView to listen to document body for any click event not working for all web pages

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, webkit

I am injecting javascript to a webkitView to listen to document body for any click event but unfortunately the script is not working for all the web pages like "https://www.zara.com", otherwise it works on other web pages like google etc ...

This is my code:

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!
    private var url = URL(string: "https://www.google.com")!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        initializeWebView()
        loadData()

    }

    private func initializeWebView() {

        let javascript = """
        window.onload = function() {
            document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {
                var tagClicked = document.elementFromPoint(evt.clientX, evt.clientY);
                window.webkit.messageHandlers.jsMessenger.postMessage(tagClicked.outerHTML.toString());
            });
        }
        """

        let userScript = WKUserScript.init(source: javascript,
                                           injectionTime: .atDocumentStart, forMainFrameOnly: true)
        webView.configuration.userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)
        webView.configuration.userContentController.add(self, name: "jsMessenger")
    }

    private func loadData() {
        let request  = URLRequest(url: url)
        webView?.load(URLRequest.init(url: url))
    }
}


extension ViewController: WKScriptMessageHandler {
    func userContentController(_ userContentController: WKUserContentController, didReceive message: WKScriptMessage) {
        print(message.body)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should init WKUserScript with `forMainFrameOnly: false` parameter.
You can find the detail information about this parameter here:
[WKUserScript forMainFrameOnly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49850682/wkuserscript-formainframeonly/49851005#49851005)

Comment: Thank's good answer also I had to inject the script atDocumentEnd after all web page's scripts are loaded